# Where could I find pseudocode for XGBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, algorithms, boosting

I was wondering whether anybody knew where I could find pseudocode for the XGBoost algorithm?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02754.pdf

Comment: Do you know if there is anything more general? The pseudocode in Chen's paper is for specific algorithms within XGBoost.

Comment: Are you interested specifically in XGBoost, or would regular old gradient boosting be sufficient?

Comment: Pseudocode for gradient boosting would help. How tricky would it to "convert" it into pseudocode for XGBoost?

Comment: You can't "convert" it, XGBoost does stuff that regular old gradient boosting doesn't do.